# How to Bridge Two Ethernet Ports on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, ethernet, bridge

How can I bridge two wired ethernet interfaces on Mac OS X (e.g. the current MacPro comes with two ethernet ports)?

Googling turned up (e.g. this [Apple forum post](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1871594) and this [openvpn post](http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2005-10/msg00029.html)) that this is fairly easy on Linux (using the brctl command) and under Windows (via Network Connections > right-click > Bridge Connections), but how is it done under Mac OS X?

BTW: There also doesn't seem to be a macport for brctl ('port search brctl' didn't turn up any results)

Note: I don't want to have 'internet sharing', which creates a new network (by handing out network addresses in a new range). I want to really 'bridge' two interfaces so to keep the same network subnet.

Comment: You need to explain what your end goal is.  The links you provided don't help.  As the first link's response post says, *"I cannot fathom what it is you are trying to do here."*

Comment: As the first link did, I am afraid that I have to suggest to look up 'network bridge' if you're not familiar with the concept. As a simplified summary, i want to use a Mac as a sort of hub.

Comment: Time to reevaluate answers, since the accepted one is from 2009. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to build a *real* Ethernet bridge (Layer 2 bridge) on Mac OS X, answer is, you simply can't without third-party software. That's just the way it is, there is nothing in the kernel or in userspace to do this.

The only software I know capable of doing this is [IPNetRouterX](http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_ipnrx_overview.html), which is not free. Never tried it myself.

Comment: Seems like this is supported since Yosemite: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18510?locale=en_US

Answer (score 31):

As of Mountain Lion, you can configure bridges using ifconfig:

```
sudo ifconfig bridge0 create
sudo ifconfig bridge0 addm en0 addm en1
sudo ifconfig bridge0 up
```

See `man ifconfig` for more options.

It doesn't work well with wifi interfaces however due to how they handle lookups.

Comment: As for the edit that should've been a comment: I assume you're not on Mountain Lion (10.8.x). Please check again that you are.

Comment: I happen to be [having trouble with wifi](http://superuser.com/q/670545/11557) -- can you give me any more data on why it doesn't work well?