# How do I use a Mac as switch (or bridge two interfaces)

Tags: macos, mac, networking, switch, bridge

I need to put a wired device (Blue-ray player), on my home wireless network's subnet, via the mac's wifi connection, as there is no wired connections upstairs.

To be more clear, what I'd like is:

```
BlueRay ---(ethernet)---> Mac ---(wifi)---> Home Router [192.168.1.1]
[192.168.1.3]        [192.168.1.4]                         |
                                                      (ethernet)
                                                           |
                                                           v
                                         Media Server PC [192.168.1.5]
```

Basically I want to bridge ethernet over to the wifi network. And 'Internet Sharing' won't do as it creates a second subnet [192.168.2.x]

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable IP forwarding on your Mac. Which can be done via the following command (you might need to restart your mac/networking interface for changes to take effect):

> sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

More info: [How do I enable IP-forwarding in MacOS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/97117/how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-in-macos-x)

Answer (score 1):

As of Mountain Lion, it might work to [configure a bridge using ifconfig](https://superuser.com/a/481543/10000):

```
sudo ifconfig bridge0 create
sudo ifconfig bridge0 addm en0 addm en1
sudo ifconfig bridge0 up
```

See `man ifconfig` for more options.