# How to access bridged Mac from behind the bridge?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, bridge

In [another thread](https://superuser.com/a/481543/257971), it was suggested that the way to bridge two Ethernet ports on a Mac running Mountain Lion was to run the following:

> sudo ifconfig bridge0 create
>
> sudo ifconfig bridge0 addm en0 addm en1
>
> sudo ifconfig bridge0 up

It works great! But I can't access the machine that is doing the bridging from the machine behind it. I'm smart enough to discern the answer might have to do with "static routes" and "netmasks," not smart enough to understand how these work. Anyone care to break it down?

Comment: If you are really creating an ethernet bridge (which it looks like you are), then routes and netmasks are not the answer.  Ethernet works at OSI layer 2 - routes and netmasks are at the ip layer, which is OSI layer 3.     -- as to what the actual problem is, not sure, but it's likely a bug in the MacOS networking stack.  If one of the ethernets is wifi, note that the original article you mention says it is not reliable on wifi.

Comment: Any chance you could link the original post in your question for reference?

Comment: Yep, Zach, I did just that.